# restoring heap property after insertion several elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, heap, complexity-theory

Let we have a binary heap, realized by an array of length  n. We write at the end of this array k elements. After that we want to restrore the heap property on this array of length n+k.

The complexity should be O(k + (logn)*log(log(n))).

My attemts. Of course we can restore the heap property of the full array with complexity O(n+k) using standart procedure. But it doesn't  satisfy this complexity.

Also I have heard about the following method. Let we make a heap on the k last elements by O(k) and after that we create a "new heap" with first element greater (if we work with max-heaps) then the tops of first heap of size n and second heap of size k and with first heap as left subheap of new heap and second heap as right subheap. After that we delete top element by O(log(n+k)). But I really don't understand how to realize this approach, when we use an array representation.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing would be to apply the "heap insert" operation on each of the k new elements, starting with the first.  This has complexity O(k log(n)), which if k is much smaller than n is better than O(k + log(n) log(log(n)))

Comment: Thank you. Of course I understand it. For this k should be not greater than log(log(n)). Also if k = O(n) than the approach with creating heap on all elements will be good in the complexity sense. But the most interesting situation is for an arbitrary k.